# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I was trying to render simple react application with web-pack, all is compiles perfectly. On runtime code fails with following stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
at checkBoxCheck (App.js:174)...
```

Here is the code with the setState:

```
//App.js
export class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { remember: false };
  }

  checkBoxCheck(event) {
    this.setState({
      remember: !this.state.remember
    });
    console.log(this.state.remember);
  }

  render() {
    let msg = this.state.remember ? "checked" : "uncheked";
    return (
      <form method="post">
        <h1>{msg}</h1>
        <label htmlFor="login">Login: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login" />
        <label htmlFor="pass"> Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="pass" />
        <label htmlFor="remember">Remeber me: </label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="remember"
          defaultChecked={this.state.remember}
          onChange={this.checkBoxCheck}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Where is syntax issue?

Also i were trying to make an checkBoxCheck 'arrow' function, that cause compiling errors:

```
    checkBoxCheck = event => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) =>({
        remember: !prevState.remember
    }));
    console.log(this.state.remember);
}

//output        
SyntaxError: D:/Projects/Learning-projects/learn-react/src/App.js: Unexpected token (53:18)

  51 |     }
  52 |
> 53 |     checkBoxCheck = event => {
     |                   ^
  54 |         this.setState((prevState, props) =>({
  55 |             remember: !prevState.remember
  56 |         }));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Webpack doesn't actually *execute* all of your code. If you want to find issues before deployment, write *tests*.

Comment: Try e.g. binding your `checkBoxCheck` method to `this` in the constructor. `this.checkBoxCheck = this.checkBoxCheck.bind(this);`

Comment: @jonrsharpe i din't get to that stage in JavaScript yet:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually forgot to bind context to the checkBoxCheck method.

```
...
<input
   type="checkbox"
   name="remember"
   defaultChecked={this.state.remember}
   onChange={this.checkBoxCheck.bind(this)} // <- .bind(this)
/>
...
```

---

#### Tips:

There are little remarks regards your code:

1. Do not bind context in `render` method.
2. Do not use `this.state` within a `this.setState` function

### Never `.bind()` in `render`

```
render() { // <- If you here
  ...
  <input
    ...
    onChange={this.checkBoxCheck.bind(this)} // <- don't do this
  />
  ...
}
```

By binding your event handlers like this, you create brand new functions every time React calls your component’s render. Instead, you can convert your function into the arrow function:

```
checkBoxCheck = event => {
  this.setState({
    remember: !this.state.remember
  });
  console.log(this.state.remember);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
...
<input
   type="checkbox"
   name="remember"
   defaultChecked={this.state.remember}
   onChange={this.checkBoxCheck} // <- there is no binding
/>
...
```

Also, you can bind all your methods inside the class constructor:

```
//App.js
export class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { remember: false };

    this.checkBoxCheck = this.checkBoxCheck.bind(this); // <- Bind your methods here
  }
...
```

and call your function without binding:

```
...
<input
   type="checkbox"
   name="remember"
   defaultChecked={this.state.remember}
   onChange={this.checkBoxCheck} // <- there is no binding
/>
...
```

### Using `this.state` within a `this.setState`

An example can be an increment function:

```
function increment() {
  this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1});
}
```

If these two setState operations is grouped together in a batch it will look be something like the following, given that value is 1:

```
setState({value: 1 + 1})
setState({value: 1 + 1})
```

This can be avoided with using callbacks which takes the previous state as the first argument:

```
function increment() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({value: prevState.value + 1}));
}
```

Then react will call the argument with the correct and updated state, even when things happen in batches. And the example above will be something like:

```
setState({value: 1 + 1})
setState({value: 2 + 1})
```

Refs:

- https://ryanfunduk.com/articles/never-bind-in-render/
- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-access-state-in-setstate.md

Comment: also i want to mention that if i use the solution with arrow function i have a compilation error :\     ERROR in ./src/App.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    SyntaxError: D:/Projects/Learning-projects/learn-react/src/App.js: Unexpected token (52:18)

      50 |     }
      51 |
    > 52 |     checkBoxCheck = event => {
         |                   ^
      53 |         this.setState({
      54 |             remember: !state.remember
      55 |         });

Comment: @WaldemarTsiamruk, you can try to use this plugin to enable this feature: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you need to bind `this.checkBoxCheck` to `this`.

Add this: `this.checkBoxCheck = this.checkBoxCheck.bind(this)` to your constructor.

Example:

```
//App.js
export class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { remember: false };

    this.checkBoxCheck = this.checkBoxCheck.bind(this);
  }

  checkBoxCheck(event) {
    this.setState({
      remember: !this.state.remember
    });
    console.log(this.state.remember);
  }

  render() {
    let msg = this.state.remember ? "checked" : "uncheked";
    return (
      <form method="post">
        <h1>{msg}</h1>
        <label htmlFor="login">Login: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login" />
        <label htmlFor="pass"> Password: </label> 
        <input type="password" name="pass" />
        <label htmlFor="remember">Remeber me: </label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="remember"
          defaultChecked={this.state.remember}
          onChange={this.checkBoxCheck}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```